# HTML Document with underlined fields for filling

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating a document in HTML that has some fields that are underlined and need to be filled dynamically, however i cant style it properly. What I need to do is this:

"Applicant's Last Name:_________bar_____________ First Name:_________foo_____________"

for the first row and then:

"School Name"_Some name_______________________________________________________"

so the text I'm filling in dynamically has to be on the lines as if it were handfilled, however i don't know its length and I'm pretty bad with css. I tried with a table where the static text is a `<td>` and the underline is another `<td>` but couldn't format it properly for the second row where by this logic i would have 2 `<td>` elements with different width than the four `<td>` elements in the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use regular `<input type="text">`fields and style them accordingly with CSS: `background: none; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black;` etc. etc.

Comment: the fields wont be filled by a user they should look like a document that is to be hand filled, only the information is already displayed over the underline. the problem is styling the width of the static text with the width of the dynamic and the underline

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean, but if you just need lines without any input functionality: Insert DIVs that have `display: inline-block`, the `width`you want, a `height` of 1em or less and `border-bottom: 1px solid black` The exact static text width is unpredictible (depends on font, font-size, text rendering of the browser etc.), but that way you can at least come close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly but it looks like you want three input types first name, last name, and school name. I used two separate divs to put them on two different lines.

HTML:

```
  <div class="first">
    <p>Applicant's Last Name: <input type="text" maxlength="20"/>First Name:<input type="text" maxlength="20"/></p>
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
    <p>School Name: <input type="text" maxlength="50"/></p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
input{
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```